# Is this a logical bug or strange statistical behavior?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have a very simple Neural Network classifier built using sklearn (see code below). The input is t time windows (currently 8) of a simple 1D time-series signal. The signal itself, as can be seen from the full code below, is a simple brownian-type random motion, with a gaussian (mean zero) delta movement at each time step.

This is where the set up get's a little less standard, as I am then creating the output class labels of 0 and 1 completely randomly. The model is then trained using these random output labels, using standard params (adam optimiser etc).

I have then built an accuracy metric which is similar to Positive predictive value (PPV), and is calculated thus: For each set of contiguous "predicted" 1s in the testing data (so ' .. 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 .. ' contains just one set), if the underlying time series signal increases during that period then this is a "hit" or a "true positive". The accuracy is then the proportion of these "1" or positive sets which are "hits".

Now, statistically this should be 50% as far as I am aware, assuming that the signal is random enough that a simple shallow NN couldn't detect the underlying pattern, and that the label assignment is random as well.

The crux of all of this is that I'm not getting 50%. I'm fairly consistently getting around 52-53%. This is done fairly archaically through a simple For loop which creates a fresh signal/label sets each time etc and then averages the results over say, 20 iterations (it only takes a few for the 53% trend to show itself).

My question is, does anyone know why is the accuracy not 50%?

Code:

```
import pandas as PD
import autograd.numpy as np
from random import gauss
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

list_of_acc = []
for k in range(10):

    ## create the data 
    time_steps = 8
    data_size = 6000
    signal_value = 500
    time_series = []
    for k in range(data_size):
        delta = gauss(0,0.5)
        signal_value = signal_value + delta
        time_series.append(signal_value)

    all_inputs = np.array([time_series[i-time_steps:i] for i in range(time_steps,len(time_series))])
    all_data = PD.DataFrame(np.array(all_inputs))
    all_data[len(all_data.columns)] = np.array([random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(len(all_data))])

    train_prop = 0.6
    test_final_index = int(train_prop*len(all_data))

    x_train = all_data.loc[:test_final_index,:len(all_data.columns) - 2]
    x_test = all_data.loc[test_final_index:,:len(all_data.columns) - 2]
    y_train = all_data.loc[:test_final_index,len(all_data.columns) - 1:]

    
    #create model
    number_classes = np.unique(y_train)
    model =  MLPClassifier(random_state=0, 
                           hidden_layer_sizes = (20,), 
                           learning_rate_init = 0.000025, #0.001 gave 0.55
                           momentum  = 0.85, 
                           solver = 'adam', 
                           batch_size = 32, 
                           max_iter = 80)

    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    
    ### now test fitted model for accuracy of +- movement
    tot_play = 0 
    total_hits = 0 
    in_play = False # this will by True whenever pred is = 1
    for i in range(test_final_index,len(all_data)-1):
        pred = model.predict(np.array([all_data.loc[i,:len(all_data.columns) - 2]]))   
        if in_play:
            if pred == 1:
                in_play = True # continue to next t steps with still in_play
            else:
                if all_data.loc[i,len(all_data.columns) - 2] > current_signal_value:
                    total_hits = total_hits + 1
                in_play = False

        else:
            if pred == 1:
                in_play = True
                tot_play = tot_play + 1
                current_signal_value = all_data.loc[i,len(all_data.columns) - 2]

    accuracy = total_hits/tot_play  
    print(accuracy)
    list_of_acc.append(accuracy)

print(np.mean(list_of_acc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the input concept "random" with the result of "has no pattern".
Avoiding pattern usually requires (1) knowledge of the patterns that will be recognized, and (2) careful construction of data to counter each potential pattern with the opposing patterns.

Just as surely as the Central Tendency Theorem says that we will get *close* to 50%, it says that hitting *exactly* 50% is less likely as the quantities grow large.

When you generate random data, the sample deviates slightly from a totally balanced distribution.  Your model is good enough to find *some* patterns in those deviations, and it learns to bias its predictions in favor of those imbalances.

---

A simple example is coin-tossing.  If you toss a coin 100 times, you are likely to find that, rather than 50 heads and 50 tails, you will have a slightly off-center split, such as 52 tails - 48 heads.  Take this as your random input.

Train your model.  It will learn that tails are more prevalent.  A horridly simplistic model will simply predict "tails" on every toss, and achieve 52% accuracy.  A more sophisticated model will find other ways to predict, but will still lean toward tails, and tend toward 52% accuracy.